# C++ Vector of bools error: "iterator not dereferencable" when assigning values

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing some code to create a dynamic 2d Vector of Booleans in C++ and then trying to assign values to it but i'm receiving the error:

```
Expression:vector<bool> iterator not dereferencable
```

my vector definition is as follows:

```
vector<vector<bool> > sol((x+1), vector<bool>(y+1));
```

I then try and assign values to the first row as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    sol[0][i] = true;
}
```

But I receive the error described above. x and y are defined previously and are integers. I have found multiple questions regarding iterators not being dereferencable but haven't been able to apply the fixes for those to my own problem so any insight is welcome, thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct. Despite what the other answer says, you can assign into a `vector<bool>` with `vec[i]=true;` like you're doing.

The issue with your code, however, is that `x+1` is the size of the outer dimension of the 2d vector, but you're using it to iterate over the inner dimension which is sized `y+1`. If `x > y`, this leads to undefined behavior.

Assuming that `x+1` is the row length, your vector is currently stored in column-major order (each inner vector represents one column). If you want row-major order instead (which is more commonly used), replace `x+1` and `y+1` in the vector initialization and then your `for` loop will work.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard mandates `std::vector<bool>` to be a specialisation of `std::vector`. In particular, the data are packed tightly, 1 bit per element.

It is therefore not possible to dereference an iterator over a vector of `bool`s: the standard does not specify a size for the `bool` type.

As for an alternative, look at `std::bitset`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did notice when I was outputting the values in the vector for testing purposes I was receiving some quite large values rather my expected "0's" and "1's".

 I'm fairly new to C++ and using vectors so could you give me a bit more of an insight into the use of bitsets or maybe some example code? I've looked at the C++ class page for it and i'm not sure how I could even start converting my code into the proposed solution.

Thanks!

Comment: But it is possible to dereference a `vector<bool>` iterator (it gives you the type `(vector<bool>::reference)` instead of `bool&`). It's also possible to assign an element like the code above is doing.

Comment: Indeed it is. The C++ committee settled on this `reference` having realised what a mess `std::vector<bool>` is. My answer is focussed on the immediate problem (the crash), and the reason for it.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the crash. You claim that it isn't possible to dereference an iterator, which is wrong. And saying "the standard does not specify a size for the `bool` type" is meaningless: The standard doesn't specify a size for the `int` type either.

Comment: Thanks both for your responses, If I could accept both answers then I would. I have adjusted my code as stated by interJay and it works, I was just getting my row/column major mixed up (newbie error). I am interested in bitsets though I'm just unsure on how to go about implementing them for my program.

Comment: I think mine is the weaker answer, so you accepted the correct one in my opinion.